# unable to show activity indicator iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am trying to show `UIActivityIndicator` on `viewDidLoad` of a screen. its working in another project but not sure why it's not displayed here.

I am calling the showSplashScreen from`viewDidLoad` of other screen.

```
+(void) showSplashScreen
{
    UIView *mainScreen = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];

    UIView *windowBlocker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mainScreen.frame];
    windowBlocker.tag = 999;
    windowBlocker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((mainScreen.frame.size.width), (mainScreen.frame.size.height), 50, 50)];
    imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:200 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor];

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [windowBlocker addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.center = mainScreen.center;
    [spinner startAnimating];
}
```

nothing happens. Any idea? I am trying for iPad.

Comment: where do you add `windowBlocker` to the screen??

Comment: i have added [mainScreen addSubview:windowBlocker]; still no luck.

Comment: You not set the color of spinner..... only

Comment: LUI add your view ... [self.view addSubView:windowBlocker];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated    {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(addSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

-(void)addSplash    {
    [[self class] showSplashScreen];
}

+(void) showSplashScreen
{
    UIView *mainScreen = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window];

    UIView *windowBlocker = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:mainScreen.frame];
    windowBlocker.tag = 999;
    windowBlocker.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((mainScreen.frame.size.width), (mainScreen.frame.size.height), 50, 50)];
    imageView.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:200 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5] CGColor];

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [windowBlocker addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.center = mainScreen.center;
    [spinner startAnimating];

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window] addSubview:windowBlocker];

}
```

As I added some delay with `0.5` because when i called function in `ViewDidLoad` or`ViewWillAppear` some reason view not initaliaze yet so i provide some delay or you can use the `viewDidAppear` for as an option of this situation like and only this function and remove `viewWillAppear` and `addSplash` and add only this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[self class] showSplashScreen];
}
```

Comment: solved . thankx. but why you added delay ?pls explain to help me understand.

Answer (score 5):

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [imageView addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.center = mainScreen.center;
    [windowBlocker addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view addSubview: mainScreen];
    [spinner startAnimating];
```

Comment: Have you tried this code with your `Xcode` project ?

Answer (score 1):

looks like the issue is that you haven't added `windowBlocker` to the screen.

try:

```
[mainScreen addSubview:windowBlocker];
```

Comment: @LUI you've confirmed with a print out the method is running yes? have you tried moving it to `viewWillAppear` rather than load

Comment: @LUI did this work? if so don't forget to upvote answers and mark top answer the one that solved your issue. So others will know what fixed it if facing a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

//Yoy forget to add windowBlocker in mainview

```
   [Self.view addSubview:windowBlocker];


UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = mainScreen.center;
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [windowBlocker addSubview:spinner];
```

//Try this code

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:windowBlocker];` try this code with your `Xcode` project with in `class method`

Answer (score 0):

Change this ... it works for you

```
       UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
       spinner.color=[UIColor greenColor];
       spinner.center = self.view.center;
      [spinner startAnimating];
      [windowBlocker addSubview:spinner];
```

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:windowBlocker];` try this code with your `Xcode` project with in `class method`